# Swift - How to get text formatting in a text editor like in the notes app? SwiftUI

Tags: swift, text, swiftui

I currently have a TextEditor, and I want to be able to add text formatting like in the notes app like this:

[image: First][image: Second]

I've tried with `UITextView.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true` but it didn't seem to work.

Any ideas will be highly appreciated.
:)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI - how to copy text to clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61772282/swiftui-how-to-copy-text-to-clipboard)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a custom TextView UIViewRepresentable and set allowsEditingTextAttributes to true there:

create a new Swift file called TextView.swift

```
import SwiftUI
struct TextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var attributedText: NSMutableAttributedString
    @State var allowsEditingTextAttributes: Bool = false
    @State var font: UIFont?

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        UITextView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.attributedText = attributedText
        uiView.allowsEditingTextAttributes = allowsEditingTextAttributes
        uiView.font = font
    }
}
```

---

Then you can add it to your content view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "")
    var body: some View {
        TextView(attributedText: $attributedText, allowsEditingTextAttributes: true, font: .systemFont(ofSize: 32))
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly!

Comment: One quick question, I want this TextView to be inclusive, so I'm working a lot with accessibility, how do I make the font to be .body like if it was SwiftUI? The standard font is reeeeaaally small.

Comment: You can also add a toolbar to the keyboard and provide two buttons to make the selected font smaller or larger but I think it will make the question too broad. For accessibility you just need to pass `.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)` and `.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true`

Comment: For additional details check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/scaling_fonts_automatically)